# How would I apply an href to the ENTIRE svg?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, href

I've got a page where I build a bunch of pie charts. On each one, I want to add an href to another location on the page.

Currently my code *works*, but it only applies the href to the individual pieces of the pie chart, as well as the text. So for example, if you click on a ring of the pie chart, it will work like it should, but if you click on the space *between* the rings, it will not.

The SVG itself is much larger and easier to click, but even though I append the anchor tag to the svg, it only applies to the elements *within* the SVG. How do I correct this behavior?

```
function pieChartBuilder(teamName, values) {
    var dataset = values;

    var trimTitle = teamName.replace(' ', '');
    trimTitle = trimTitle.toLowerCase();

    var width = 175,
        height = 175,
        cwidth = 8;

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc();

    var svg = d3.select("#pieChart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("a") // here is where I append the anchor tag to the SVG, but it only applies to the individual elements within.
        .attr("href", ("#" + trimTitle))
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")

    var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter().append("g");
    var path = gs.selectAll("path")
        .data(function (d) { return pie(d); })
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i); })
        .attr("d", function (d, i, j) { return arc.innerRadius(5 + cwidth * j).outerRadius(3 + cwidth * (j + 1))(d); });

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "title")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", (0 - (height / 2.5)))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("fill", "#808080")
        .text(teamName);

}
```

Comment: your appending _to_ the svg.  Don't you want to create an `<a/>` and append the `svg` to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have the selectors the wrong way round.  You want to have the `svg` inside an `a` tag right?:

```
d3.select("#pieChart")
  .append("a")
  .append("svg");
```

You (1) select the `pieChart`, then (2) append an `a` tag to it, then you (3) append the `svg` to that.

Comment: Oh weird, I was certain that if you appended the `a` tag to the `svg` it would work, but I can see why that wouldn't be the case now that I'm looking at it. Thanks!